# what does 'real' mean when someone says it while they know it not real

Tags: meaning

the following excerpt comes from "Dinosaurs Before Dark" by Mary Pope Osborne

> “Help! A monster!” said Annie.
> “Yeah, sure,” said Jack. “A real monster in Frog Creek, Pennsylvania.”
> “Run, Jack!” said Annie. She ran up the road.
> Oh, brother.
> This is what he got for spending time with his seven-year-old sister.

clearly, Jack knows it not a real monster. there is no any monsters in Frog Creek. does 'real' in his reply function as some kind of sarcasm?

Comment: Please correct your spelling "Jot Ior spendinJ".

Comment: “A real monster in Frog Creek, Pennsylvania.” is sarcastic. “A monster in Frog Creek, Pennsylvania.” would also be sarcastic. Sarcasm is about the meaning of your statement and its relationship to what you actually believe, it's not a matter of using a single word.

Answer (score 0):

M+W has one definition for [yeah](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yeah)

> often used sarcastically in phrases like ***yeah, right*** and ***yeah, sure*** to express *doubt or disbelief*

> "I'm a really big fan," gushed [Al Gore]. "Yeah, right," sneered Miss Love.

"*Yeah, sure*" and *real* in the OP's example function as some kind of sarcasm.

Comment: _Yeah, right! A real fairy on the top of the Christmas tree! Sure!_ Sarcasm. Uttered with a certain tone of voice.